# Can you do GET request inside HTTP POST by calling .Result on async method?

Tags: c#, python, flask, http-post, http-get

I have a service that calls API GET request and return boolean.

```
Task<bool> LoginExist(string email, string password);
```

In the controller, I have the code below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string email, string password)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("here");
        bool login_result = _accountService.LoginExist(email, password).Result;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(login_result);

        if (login_result)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, false);
            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
        }
        else
        { Redirect("Register"); }

        return Redirect("Register");
    }
```

However, when I test it, after I click Login, which triggers post request, I can tell GET is successfully executed in my flask api (it returns status 200), however, it never goes to the IF statement or ELSE statement in the code above. Instead, it just kept running...

I wonder if we can use GET within POST and if not, does anyone have better way to approach this?

I added what I have in service:

```
    public async Task<bool> LoginExist(string email, string password)
    {
        string url = string_url;
        LoginVerification str = await url.WithHeaders(new { Accept = "application /json", User_Agent = "Flurl" }).GetJsonAsync<LoginVerification>();

        return str.login_valid;
    }
```

Comment: A GET is a GET, a POST is a POST. A POST can return data. What is your question?

Comment: @John So I use GET to call the api which returns a json dictionary, I need to know the value of this json dictionary['login_valid']. And it is treated as a boolean (the result is either true or false). The problem is when I call this boolean in HTTP Post, it does not seem to work. If this is unsolvable, I have no clue how I can do user authentication in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here has nothing to do with GET vs. POST.  It's how you're using an async method.  Accessing the `Result` property directly is not the proper way to get the result of an async task.

Either change it to call `GetAwaiter` and `GetResult` like so:

```
bool login_result = _accountService.LoginExist(email, password).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Or better yet, make your action method `async` and use the `await` keyword to wait for the result.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(string email, string password)
{
    // ...
    bool login_result = await _accountService.LoginExist(email, password);
    // ...
}
```

Your intent will be clearer this way and it'll be easier to get things right.

Comment: I tried the first way of calling GetAwaiter and GetResult but it does not seem to work..

Comment: Seems like if I get rid of the bool login_result, it will start working fine...maybe there is something wrong with service?

Comment: Thanks for saving my night! The second way worked!